# WPF Creating a Custom Border around control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, controltemplate

I want to create a simple border around certain controls to create a stylised panel. I've created the border around one control but now I want to create it in such away that I can reuse it on any other controls throughout the applications. I've created a User Control to do it but I was unable to get the User Control to resize to the contents. Is there a way to do the same thing in XAML e.g. with a ControlTemplate in Resources.xaml?

```
<Border Background="LightGray" 
            BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
            BorderThickness="1" 
            ClipToBounds="True"
            Opacity="0.80">
        <Border Background="#25FFFFFF" 
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                BorderThickness="1" 
                Margin="-2">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10"/>
            </Border.Effect><!--Any Control - Insert TextBlock, Button, ContentPresenter -->
     </Border>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, and the border provides no functional value, it is just a visual decoration you want to apply to certain controls, you may want to consider an [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx).

One of the uses for an `Adorner` is to apply a visual overlay to `UIElements`, which sounds like your goal here.  That MSDN Article also provides an example and a simple search will yield plenty of custom `Adorner` examples.